# Progress bar in foreach function not working

Tags: c#, foreach, progress-bar

The program i am designing makes an image by getting the file name of the image, searches for that name in a cdb and then makes a picture with the data from that database item.All of that works. What i want to do now is add a progress bar because if you're doing for a large amount of pics it can take a while so a progress bar would help keep track of it. Here is the code i am using but the progress in the progress bar does not advance until the end i want to avoid using background worker(if i can).

```
   private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string folder = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
            DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
            FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.jpg");
            int count = Files.Length;
            int current = 0;
            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                string path = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name);
                int cardid = Convert.ToInt32(path);
                if (Program.CardData.ContainsKey(cardid))
                {
                    DevPro_CardManager.cardmaker.IMG = LoadBitmap(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "//" + file.Name);
                    string lev = Program.CardData[cardid].Level.ToString();
                    comboBox2.SelectedItem = lev;
                    string att = Program.CardData[cardid].Attribute.ToString();
                    if (att == "1")
                    {
                        att = "earth";
                    }
                    else if (att == "2")
                    {
                        att = "water";
                    }
                    else if (att == "4")
                    {
                        att = "fire";
                    }
                    else if (att == "8")
                    {
                        att = "wind";
                    }
                    else if (att == "16")
                    {
                        att = "light";
                    }
                    else if (att == "32")
                    {
                        att = "dark";
                    }
                    else if (att == "64")
                    {
                        att = "divine";
                    }
                    comboBox1.SelectedItem = att;
                    if (Program.CardData[cardid].Atk.ToString() == "-2")
                    {
                        textBox2.Text = "????";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        textBox2.Text = Program.CardData[cardid].Atk.ToString();
                    }
                    if (Program.CardData[cardid].Def.ToString() == "-2")
                    {
                        textBox1.Text = "????";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        textBox1.Text = Program.CardData[cardid].Def.ToString();
                    }
                    string ctp = Program.CardData[cardid].Type.ToString();
                    if (ctp == "2" || ctp == "130" || ctp == "65538" || ctp == "131074" || ctp == "262146" || ctp == "524290")
                    {
                        ctp = "spell";
                    }
                    else if (ctp == "4" || ctp == "1048580" || ctp == "131076")
                    {
                        ctp = "trap";
                    }
                    else if (ctp == "129" || ctp == "161")
                    {
                        ctp = "ritual";
                    }
                    else if (ctp == "65" || ctp == "97")
                    {
                        ctp = "fusion";
                    }
                    else if (ctp == "8193" || ctp == "8225" || ctp == "12321")
                    {
                        ctp = "synchro";
                    }
                    else if (ctp == "8388609" || ctp == "8388641")
                    {
                        ctp = "xyz";
                    }
                    else if (ctp == "33" || ctp == "545" || ctp == "1057" || ctp == "2081" || ctp == "4129" || ctp == "4194337")
                    {
                        ctp = "effect";
                    }
                    else if (ctp == "17" || ctp == "4113")
                    {
                        ctp = "normal";
                    }
                    else if (ctp == "16401")
                    {
                        ctp = "token";
                    }
                    comboBox3.SelectedItem = ctp;
                    GenerateCard();
                    ImageResizer.CropImage(361, 523, pictureBox1.Image, @"anime cards\" + Path.GetFileName(file.Name));
                    int cardcount = +1;
                    label8.Text = cardcount.ToString();
                }      
                current++;
                progressBar1.Value = current / count;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using BackgroundWorker? You either need to use it or create a thread and manage it yourself.

Comment: cause i have never gotten background worker to work for me if someone could code this in background worker then great but no matter what i have tried background worker has never worked for me

Comment: Using another thread is your best bet, despite the difficulty. Your UI will otherwise hang while the work is done and the application will likely be A) unresponsive which is a bad UX B) The progress bar won't work, which as you are aware presents its own problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write down below line after your progressbar value change

```
progressBar1.Value = current / count;
Application.DoEvents();
```

The Application.DoEvents() will apply the changes to the UI and refresh it so that you will be able to see the new changes to UI.

Comment: Also consider integer division you should set progressBar1.Value = (current * 100) / count;
to actually get the progress value greater than 0.

Comment: it works but not as smooth as i would like if i used background worker how would i go about it as i have never gotten it to work

Comment: progressBar1.Value = current / count; i cannot understand logic behind this line. Actually you should set the max value of your progressbar equal to count before foreach loop and then in foreach loop you should write

progressBar1.Value = current;

Comment: it because of the the process run i select a folder with the images in it then count is equal to the number of images in that folder and i changed it to what vahidnd said in first comment as it works better that way

Comment: setting max value of progressbar outside the for loop and then just assign the current value to it will eliminate the overhead of calculation  (current * 100) / count

Answer (score 5):

I would prefer a BackgroundWorker over DoEvents. It's a much cleaner way to handle what really should be a background task.

The invoking is not nearly as complex as it's described on MSDN thanks to generics.

```
ControlName.Invoke(new Action(() => { /* UI update commands */ }));
```

**Update: Added example**

Here is a very basic example of a successful BackgroundWorker. There are a few things to note. The conversion to floating point to calculate percentage correctly, as well as using a for loop instead of foreach so the counter is inherent. The only call to a form object in the DoWork event handler uses `this.Invoke` with a generic delegate to safely call on UI objects to update, and finally the file list is passed to the BackgroundWorker via the eventArgs.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BackgroundWorker fileParser;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        fileParser = new BackgroundWorker();
        fileParser.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        fileParser.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(fileParser_DoWork);
        fileParser.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(fileParser_ProgressChanged);

        // Emulating the FolderBrowserDialog results here
        List<String> fileNames = new List<String> { "File 1", "File 2", "File 3", "File 4", "File 5" };
        fileParser.RunWorkerAsync(fileNames);
    }

    void fileParser_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Update progress bar here
        tbOutput.Text += e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "% | ";
    }

    void fileParser_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        List<String> fileNames = e.Argument as List<String>;

        for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.Count; i++)
        {
            // Do intense work here
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            this.Invoke(new Action(() => { tbOutput.Text += fileNames[i] + ": "; }));
            float completePercent = ((float)(i + 1) / (float)fileNames.Count) * 100;

            // Send event to update progress bar here
            fileParser.ReportProgress(Convert.ToInt32(completePercent));
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: I agree with @Lathejockey81 its more cleaner. Here is a tutorial which might help you understand [**BackgroundWorker**](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/83317/BackgroundWorker-and-ProgressBar-demo)

Comment: i tried that tutorial but still doesnt work now it just does nothing on button click

Comment: @outlaw1994 Check again you must be missing something..or else  you didn't understood the concept of `Backgroundworker` completely ..I suggest you read about `Backgroundworker`

Comment: im looking around for some in depth background worker tutorial thanks for now i will accept patels answer as it did work

Comment: If you're still having trouble with BackgroundWorker maybe you could post the code where it is failing and we can help you find the flaw. I understand the first time working with background threads can be confusing, but they are incredibly useful and a good topic to tackle. I had never actually used a BackgroundWorker class before I threw together that example, but I understand how multiple threads work so it was easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

It is just you cannot see it but it is updated.

value should be between 0 and 100.

try:

```
progressBar1.Value = (current / count) * 100;
```

Comment: that didnt work but i changed it to this which did work progressBar1.Value = (current * 100) / count